# Format telephone numbers, keeping only digits

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a spreadsheet that has phone numbers in the cells that are typed out like this:

+1(313)313-3333

and I need these numbers to all be plain and look like this 3133133333 (with no 1 in front).

So I have a column of 200 phone number that all need to be edited and I do not want to edit by hand. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
=1*RIGHT(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"[^\d]",),10)
```

Comment: This would be better if you expanded on _how_ this solves the Asker's problem.