# How can I convert a list of phone numbers from 404-313-2974 to (404) 313-2974?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of phone numbers entered into Google Spreadsheet in this format: 404-313-2974

How can I convert this entered cell into (404) 313-2974 ?

Comment: Related [Convert phone number format from (404)-313-2974 to 404-313-2974](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/125953/88163), [Format telephone numbers, keeping only digits](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114870/88163)

Answer (score 1):

With some regex :

```
=REGEXREPLACE(
     REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^...","\($0\)")
  ,"\)-","\) ")
```

First `regexreplace` job is to add some parenthesis.
Second one is to remove the first hyphen `-`.

---

[image]